# Extra column in Excel Power pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I created a power pivot table in Excel 2010 but I want to add an extra dimension column, it looks like this now:
[Excel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nK3D.jpg)

Now I want to add an extra column with dimensions, to make it look like this:
[Excel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJaNE.jpg)

If I add it to the rowlabels it will look like this:
[Excel3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ptM.jpg)
which is clearly not how I want it to look. Any fix for this?

/edit @QHarr
here it is, it's all in Dutch and it gets it's data from a SQL server 2013 database, I thought it would not be relevant since the question is more general Excel Pivot table. Btw the Alt B M shortcut didn't work and I couldn't find the correct one so I made a pic:
[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wj8yV.jpg)
oh yeah it's still wip, I know it's a bit of a mess.

Comment: Is it connected to a data model? Can you add it via the data model? Alt + B + M (I think...to open)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select any cell with a client (say, "A"), and right-click it.
2. In the pop-up menu, select tab "Layout and Print"
3. Select "Show Item Labels in Tabular form"
4. Remove subtotals for "Client" if you have them on.

[image]